# Передача значения переменной из консоли в make

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, environment-variables

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли как-то из консоли передать значение переменной, заданной в `Makefile`?

У меня в `php`-проекте есть `Makefile` с такой командой:

```
create-file:
    echo "текст в файле" > $EXPECTED_VALUE.php
```

Такой вариант не работает:

```
make create-file --expected-value=new_filename
```

**UPD**

Пример текста для записи в переменную в Makefile

```html
VARIABLE="<?php

          namespace App\Form\${CLASS_NAME};

          use App\Form\${CLASS_NAME}\Request\${CLASS_NAME}CreateRequest;
          use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
          use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
          use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

          class ${CLASS_NAME}Type extends AbstractType
          {
              public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
              {
                  $builder
                      ->add('name', null, [
                          'label' => 'Название'
                      ]);
              }

              public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
              {
                  $resolver->setDefaults([
                      'data_class' => ${CLASS_NAME}Request::class,
                  ]);
              }
          }
"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Имя переменной надо записать в фигурных скобках:

   ```
   create-file:
       echo "текст в файле" > ${EXPECTED_VALUE}.php
   ```
2. Передавайте как переменную окружения:

   ```
   EXPECTED_VALUE=file_with_text make create-file
   ```
3. Проверка:

   ```
   cat file_with_text.php
   ```

**UPD**

***Alexey Ten*** подсказывает о возможности прямой передачи значений как аргументов:

```
make create-file EXPECTED_VALUE=file_with_text
```

Comment: Добавлю, что конкретно `make` умеет получать переменные как параметры программы. `make create-file EXPECTED_VALUE=file_with_text` тоже сработает. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding

Comment: да все сработало спасибо! Но не могли бы вы еще подсказать как правильней будет записать текст с переносами строк и различными символами? у меня сейчас символы обрезаются и переносы с отступами не учитываются.. обновил первый пост

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xZJLPWG.png

Comment: Это уже дикость формировать исходники через `make`. Откуда берется вообще этот кусок исходника в вашем конкретном случае? И да, это скорее другой вопрос, не стоит править существующий.

Comment: костыльно выглядет да но все же.. там текст статический всегда будет, нужно просто файлы с определенным внутри текстом создавать

Comment: Попробуйте это сформулировать как новый вопрос. Пока не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать.